# flutter file not found error while building for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I have been trying to follow a Udemy course for making a flutter app in which the basic structure for the app is downloaded from github - https://github.com/reedbarger/fluttershare

However when I try to build it for ios, it does not launch on the emulator and shows the following on the output log

```
[ios/.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/example] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in example...                         
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/rishika/flutter/.pub-cache/global_packages/geolocator_example/pubspec.lock' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
pub get failed (66; Cannot open file, path = '/Users/rishika/flutter/.pub-cache/global_packages/geolocator_example/pubspec.lock' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))
exit code 66
```

Comment: clear flutter cache folder from flutter sdk and run command `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: just did that and no issues found. Still doesn't build successful after tho